# NoSuchFieldException when using getDeclaredField() and field exists

Tags: java, reflection

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: c
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
>   at ru.onlymc.OnlyMZ.CustomEntityType.getPrivateStatic(CustomEntityType.java:177)

**Method:**

```
private static Object getPrivateStatic(Class clazz, String f) throws Exception {
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(f);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return field.get(null);
}
```

**Calling:**

```
private static void a(Class paramClass, String paramString, int paramInt) {
    try {
        ((Map) getPrivateStatic(sg.class, "c")).put(paramString, paramClass);
        //...
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**sg.class** (from decompile to sure about required fields really exists)**:**

```
private static Map c = new HashMap();
private static Map d = new HashMap();
private static Map e = new HashMap();
private static Map f = new HashMap();
private static Map g = new HashMap();
public static HashMap a = new LinkedHashMap();
```

Comment: You cannot get static fields with getDEclaredField, it is not entirely clear why. There have been questions on this before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change private static final field using Java reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't reproduce this one.

Here's the full source code that I ran:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ReflectionTest {

    private static Object getPrivateStatic(Class clazz, String f) throws Exception {
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(f);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(null);
    }

    private static void a(Class paramClass, String paramString, int paramInt) {
        try {
            ((Map) getPrivateStatic(sg.class, "c")).put(paramString, paramClass);
            //...
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        a(String.class, "test", 0);
        sg.printC();
    }
}

class sg {
    private static Map c = new HashMap();
    private static Map d = new HashMap();
    private static Map e = new HashMap();
    private static Map f = new HashMap();
    private static Map g = new HashMap();
    public static HashMap a = new LinkedHashMap();

    public static void printC() {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

This was the output I got when I ran it:

```
{test=class java.lang.String}
```

Given that you haven't specified the full decompiled source of the `sg` class, I can only guess at a couple of things that may have happened:

- There is more than one class named `sg`, your code is using one of them but your decompiled output comes from a different one.
- The fields exist within an inner class inside `sg`.

**EDIT**: the class `sg` you linked to below appears to contain a static field `c`, and contains no inner class, so I would expect to be able to use reflection to access this field.  I cannot use your `sg` class with the `ReflectionTest` class I wrote above because it depends on numerous other classes with obfuscated names such as `xk`.

I can only conclude that you have some confusion about exactly which class you are attempting to access the field `c` from.  I suggest altering your `getPrivateStatic` method to the following, which may provide a more helpful error message, including the name of the class and all of the fields within it:

```
    private static Object getPrivateStatic(Class clazz, String f) throws Exception {
        try {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(f);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field.get(null);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // Throw a more helpful exception.
            throw new NoSuchFieldException(
                "Could not find field named '" + f + "' in class '" + clazz +
                "'.  All fields: " + Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredFields()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: sg.class with source code of reflection: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xgzo8efpnf7dwt/sg.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the field of the object null. See documentation on [Field.get(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object))

You need to provide an object to get its field content. Or you need to provide a class to get a static fields content.

So you should write the following:

```
private static Object getPrivateStatic(Class clazz, String f) throws Exception {
  Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(f);
  field.setAccessible(true);
  return field.get(clazz);
}
```

btw. It is not considered good programming style to use reflection in production code since it e.g. makes refactoring problematic.

If you still need to use reflection (or are not working on production-code), use a framework for this kind of stuff (accessing private static field). With e.g. [PrivilegedAccessor](https://code.google.com/p/privilegedaccessor/) this method would be a 1-liner:

```
PA.getValue(clazz, f);
```

Comment: From the documentation page linked to: 'If the underlying field is a static field, the obj argument is ignored; it may be null. '.  The problem here is most definitely not the line `field.get(null)`.